# How could I detect if one php script is running from the in app browser or the phone browser

Tags: php, android, windows-mobile

I have an app for windows mobile and it runs a php script, so I want to know wether the script was called within the app or if it was called from the phone browser?

For example in android I can use this condition

```
// Android (in-app)
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.company.app") {
    echo 'Android (in-app)';
}
```

so, what would be the condition for windows app?

Thank you.

Comment: It's difficult as they're both based on chromium. Perhaps if you explained the reasoning, I could suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` gives info about the browser, I imagine that would be a different value for an app and a web browser.

Comment: I just need to show a message if the script was called within the app. I have the solution for android and iOS, but not for Windows Mobile.

Comment: And why would $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] not serve you? You could at least comment on it.